# UITableview with 2 cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to build an app with 2 cell on a tableview
the header that will have the Headlines and the second that will have the normal feeds.

My question is how to connect this two cells 
The code for the raw feeds are working

Example:

```
      // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return self.posts.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        // Configure the cell...
            let post  = self.posts[indexPath.row]
            cell.title.text = post.title?.utf8Data?.attributedString?.string
            if let imageUrl = post.imageUrl {
                cell.imgView?.downloadImage(from: imageUrl)
            }
            let myFormatter = DateFormatter()
            myFormatter.dateStyle = .none
            myFormatter.timeStyle = .short
            cell.pubDate.text = myFormatter.string(from: post.pubDate!) // What gives?

        return cell
    }
}
```

[image: MainStoryBoard]

Comment: what do you mean by connect the two cells?

Comment: google prototype cells .. your prototype cells would need a fixed reuseIdentifier so you can instantiate the correct one in cellForRow.

Comment: oh and the count is off.. you got n posts + 1 headline.. so you got one cell to little.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by filling a solid color, like white, for both the cells and set Table View separator to none.

```
tableView.separatorStyle = .none
```

And if you want to create a serious of such combined cells, then add a view to the bottom of the second cell, i.e. Feed Row, and fill that view with other color, like grey. This view will work as a separator for serious.

Comment: It appears this does not answer the question. I am fairly certain the OP (Original Poster) wants to know how to connect the cells to code.

Comment: me to ;) I wrote this as a comment but who knows ;) the op should say what he wants

Comment: He wants two types of cells, the first one should always be of Header type, and the others should be of feed type. I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with separators

Comment: Should the headline scroll with the rest of the `tableView`? If not, just make a custom headerview.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you let your tableview empty in storyboard. (delete all cells)

What I usually do, and what I feel is more flexible and cleaner in terms of code and files, is always use custom cells.

Create a subclass of `UITableViewCell` for each cell type you need (here, 2). One could be `HeaderCell`, and the other could be `FeedCell`.

If you use the "Create UITableViewCell class" I think you can find in Xcode (haven't used it in a long time), it should create the class for you, as well as a .xib file. If you don't have the corresponding .xib just create it and link it manually.

The .xib file is where you will put your labels, connect the outlets and maange everything you need. That's where you'll remake the cells you deleted ealier on. I think you can actually cut and paste in the xib and it might work.

Now you have a custom class, with its corresponding xib, which you can use as a cell.

Make sure your tableview is connected as delegate and datasource in storyboard (it should already be done in your setup).

In `ViewDidLoad` you will need to register all your cell classes to the tableview.

That is done using [this method call on your tableview property (outlet)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614937-register)

I'm not sure how to write it in swift, but it's
`MyTableView.Register(nib, key)` in pseudo code.

Both the parameters come from your custom cell class (it's the .Nib and the class name, which you could hardcode). I usually do MyHeaderCell.Nib and MyHeaderCell.Key that are put in static, but that you can do however you want.

Now that your tableview is aware of the cells it will have to display, you just have to manage it in your `cellForRow` method.

Simply do it by index :

```
var cell;
if (indexPath.Row == 0)
    {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HeaderCell", for: indexPath) as! HeaderCell
    }
    else
    {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FeedCell", for: indexPath) as! FeedCell

    }

    let post  = self.posts[indexPath.row]
    cell.title.text = post.title

    return cell
```

And there you go :)

I've never done swift so there are certainly syntax mistakes but the idea is how you should do it.